# Get SoapBody Element value

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

Here is the response I get from server, 
Although I can take the `MM7Version` element value, I cannot get the `Status` element value. it returns null.

**SoapMeesage XML Response:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<mm7:TransactionID SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:mm7="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2">TID.BIP_TRASNID.20041103.135200.001</mm7:TransactionID>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<MM7Version>5.6.0</MM7Version>
<Status><StatusCode>2602</StatusCode><StatusText>Invalid status</StatusText></Status>
<MessageID></MessageID>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Java Code:**

```
SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, endpoint);

  SOAPEnvelope env= response.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();

  SOAPBody sb = env.getBody();
  Name ElName = env.createName("Status");

//Get child elements with the name XElement
  Iterator it = sb.getChildElements(ElName);

  //Get the first matched child element.
  //We know there is only one.
  SOAPBodyElement sbe = (SOAPBodyElement) it.next();


  //Get the value for XElement
  String MyValue =   sbe.getValue();

  System.out.println("MyValue: "+MyValue);
```

Comment: what is similar with dublicate question? I can get whole XML value. Why I cannot retrive Status field while get other ones? response.writeTo(System.out); is used for this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coded a method by inspiring http://www.coderanch.com/t/640002/Web-Services/java/Error-parsing-SOAP-response-message

```
private static MmsResponse getMmsResponse(SOAPMessage response) throws SOAPException {

  MmsResponse mmsResponse = new MmsResponse();

  Iterator itr=response.getSOAPBody().getChildElements();
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
      Node node=(Node)itr.next();
      if (node.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element ele=(Element)node;

          switch (ele.getNodeName()) {
        case "MM7Version":
           mmsResponse.setMm7Version(ele.getTextContent());
           break;

        case "MessageID":
           mmsResponse.setMessageID(ele.getTextContent());
           break;

        case "Status":
           NodeList statusNodeList = ele.getChildNodes();
           Status status = new Status();
           for(int i=0;i<statusNodeList.getLength();i++){
             Element statusElement = (Element) statusNodeList.item(i);
              switch (statusElement.getNodeName()) {
              case "StatusCode":
                 status.setStatusCode(ele.getChildNodes().item(i).getTextContent());
                 break;                     
              case "StatusText":
                 status.setStatusText(ele.getChildNodes().item(i).getTextContent());
                 break; 

              default:
                 break;
              }
           }

           mmsResponse.setStatus(status);
           break;


        default:
           break;
        }

      } else if (node.getNodeType()==Node.TEXT_NODE) {
          //do nothing here most likely, as the response nearly never has mixed content type
          //this is just for your reference
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with the [Conversion Box](http://capsulesforthejavamind.blogspot.in/2015/01/conversion-box.html) component ...

```
import java.util.Map;

import cjm.component.cb.map.ToMap;

public class Trying
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        String parseXML = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'><SOAP-ENV:Header><mm7:TransactionID SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand='1' xmlns:mm7='http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2'>TID.BIP_TRASNID.20041103.135200.001</mm7:TransactionID></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><MM7Version>5.6.0</MM7Version><Status><StatusCode>2602</StatusCode><StatusText>Invalid status</StatusText></Status><MessageID></MessageID></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

        Map<String, Object> parsedMap = new ToMap().convertToMap(parseXML); // you will need the conversion box component for this

        Map<String, Object> envelopeMap = (Map<String, Object>) parsedMap.get("SOAP-ENV:Envelope");

        Map<String, Object> bodyMap = (Map<String, Object>) envelopeMap.get("SOAP-ENV:Body");

        String MM7Version = (String) bodyMap.get("MM7Version");

        System.out.println("MM7Version = " + MM7Version);

        Map<String, Object> statusMap = (Map<String, Object>) bodyMap.get("Status");

        System.out.println("Status Code = " + statusMap.get("StatusCode"));
        System.out.println("Status Text = " + statusMap.get("StatusText"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Output

```
 -------- XML Detected -------- 
 -------- Map created Successfully -------- 
MM7Version = 5.6.0
Status Code = 2602
Status Text = Invalid status
```