# Get Strings from SOAP Message in Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

How can I get specific parts from a SOAP message and get their values?

For example, if the `.wsdl` message is this:

```
<wsdl:message name="theRequest">
      <wsdl:part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
      <wsdl:part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
      <wsdl:part name="someMsg"  type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

I want to get `someMsg` value and save it into a String variable.

I was looking at this: [Get SoapBody Element value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355100/get-soapbody-element-value), but didn't really understand much. If someone could provide an explanation or any kind of guide it would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The normal way to create a client to deal with *SOAP* messages and *web service* are; generate the beans from the `.xsd` schemas, and all the stubs from `.wsdl` to invoke the *web service* (in this case for *Java* for example could be using *JAXWS* and *JAXB*).

Note also that typically `.wsdl` define the service, but If you ask how to parse a request is better to show the `.xsd`.

Anyway of course you can invoke a *web service* using directly and *apache http client* or so to make a POST and then process the response... but note that this is not a recommended way to deal with a lot of request and response from a SOAP web service because then you've to parse manually each response to make your business. Supposing that this is your case you can do something similar to this to process your *SOAP message* ( I use `javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage` since seems that you want to use this class based on the links you put in the question).

For example if you're receiving a SOAP message like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
    <theRequest>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <someMsg>sooomeMessage</someMsg>
      </theRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You can do something like:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class SOAPMessageTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // create message factory
        MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        // headers for a SOAP message
        MimeHeaders header = new MimeHeaders();     
        header.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

        // inputStream with your SOAP content... for the 
        // test I use a fileInputStream pointing to a file
        // which contains the request showed below
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/path/yourSOAPReq.xml");

        // create the SOAPMessage
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = mf.createMessage(header,fis);
        // get the body
        SOAPBody soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
        // find your node based on tag name
        NodeList nodes = soapBody.getElementsByTagName("someMsg");

        // check if the node exists and get the value
        String someMsgContent = null;
        Node node = nodes.item(0);
        someMsgContent = node != null ? node.getTextContent() : "";

        System.out.println(someMsgContent);
    }

}
```

*EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:*

It works for me also in **Java 8**, right now my only guess is that something is happening with the `FileInputStream`. Can you try the follow code which is the same but get the request from a `String` instead from a *File*.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class SOAPMessageTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // create message factory
        MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        // headers for a SOAP message
        MimeHeaders header = new MimeHeaders();     
        header.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

        String request = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"+
         "<soapenv:Body>"+
           "<theRequest>"+
             "<username>user</username>"+
             "<password>password</password>"+
             "<someMsg>sooomeMessage</someMsg>"+
           "</theRequest>"+
          "</soapenv:Body>"+
        "</soapenv:Envelope>";
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes());

        // create the SOAPMessage
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = mf.createMessage(header,is);
        // get the body
        SOAPBody soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
        // find your node based on tag name
        NodeList nodes = soapBody.getElementsByTagName("someMsg");
        System.out.println(nodes.getClass().getName());
        // check if the node exists and get the value
        String someMsgContent = null;
        Node node = nodes.item(0);
        someMsgContent = node != null ? node.getTextContent() : "";

        System.out.println(someMsgContent);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! However, I have problem with the code provided. When I print it, I just get `null`. I think the problem is on this line: `Node node = nodes.item(0)`. Eclipse gives me an error saying that it needs to be casted to a `Node`. So I changed it to: `Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0)` and I get no compiler errors. Not sure why it is saying that the String is null though.

Comment: @m.o maybe the `(Node)` cast is needed due to type returned by `org.w3c.dom.NodeList.item()` depends on java version. I'm using **Java 7** and here the [`item()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html#item(int)) methods returns `Node` so cast is not required. About why is your string `null`, can you share the `xml` which are you trying to parse `:)`?

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused then. I thought the `/path/yourSOAPReq.xml` was the the SOAP message posted above. Can you provide a sample `xml` of what that file should probably look like? Is it just a regular `xml` file with the attributes defined in the `.xsd`?

Comment: @m.o yes It was `:)`, simply I though that you're trying with another one since it not works for you... If you're using the sample `xml` from the answer as a source this code must works. Which java version are you using?

Comment: I am using Java 8. Thanks for helping out, by the way!

Comment: @m.o I just try with *Java 8*  and works also for me... my only guess now is what I put on the edit, can you try it? hope this works `: P`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked with the String. In addition, I restarted my computer and it works with the File now. So weird, lol.

Comment: @m.o yes weird!, it was my last attempt `:)`. Nice to help you!