# Get Strings from SOAP Message in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, soap

How can I parse specific parts from a SOAP message and get their values?

For example, if the soap response message is this:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap12:Body>
     <GetCountryListResponse xmlns="http://example.org/">
       <GetCountryListResult>
         <string>string</string>
         <string>string</string>
       </GetCountryListResult>
     </GetCountryListResponse>
   </soap12:Body>
 </soap12:Envelope>
```

I want to get the GetCountryListResult value and save it into a String variable.

I found a good answer in Java for this question:

[Get Strings from SOAP Message in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349144/get-strings-from-soap-message-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

This example will read your xml from file and build list of strings found, but you can get and idea how you can parse it.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\soap.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    var sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    var str = sr.ReadToEnd();
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(str);

    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
    manager.AddNamespace("soap12", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
    manager.AddNamespace("", "http://example.org/");
    XmlNodeList xnList = document.SelectNodes("//soap12:Envelope/soap12:Body/GetCountryListResponse/GetCountryListResult", manager);
    if (xnList.Count == 0) return;

    XmlNode countryListResult = xnList[0];
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    foreach (XmlNode childNode in countryListResult.ChildNodes)
    {
        result.Add(childNode.FirstChild.Value);
    }
}
```

You will need to add error handling too.

Answer (score 0):

var service = new WebService();
    var result = service.Invoke(soapAction, method, parameters);

```
XNamespace nsSoap = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
XNamespace ns = "link-to-namespace";

// Look for the "Fault" element in the response. If present, there was an error.
var fault = result.Root.Element("{" + nsSoap + "}Body").Element("{" + ns_soap + "}Fault");
if (error != null)
{
    var codeWithNs = error.Element("{" + nsSoap + "}Code").Element("{" + ns_soap + "}Value").Value;
    var codeSplit = codeWithNs.Split(':');
    var code = codeSplit.Length == 2 ? codeSplit[1] : codeSplit[0];
    if (code == "InvalidUsernameOrPassword")
    {
        throw new InvalidUsernameOrPasswordException();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Something went wrong.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The WebService class does not have an Invoke method. Also, did you mean to type "fault" rather than "error" in the if statement?